# iOS Emulator Compile Error

Tags: smartface.io

I'm trying to compile the iOS Emulator from Github (https://github.com/smartface/iOS-Emulator) to be able to use it on iOS 8.3, but the compile process fails with the following errors:

`(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ESpratIOSPlayer", referenced from:
(null): "splog(int, char const*, char const*, ...)", referenced from:
(null): "SpEventGroup::FireEvent(TEventID, int, char*, SpBrParcelable*)", referenced from:
(null): "SpBrParcelable::GetEventGroup()", referenced from:
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Can you try the emulator at the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/0t9fef9jpdhb7bx/SmartfaceEmulator.zip?dl=0

Please only open that zip folder directly on your Mac.

Comment: I've tried and I get the exact same errors